# Qt Creator: Supplying symbols to the Clang Code Model

Tags: c++, qt, clang, qt-creator, syntax-highlighting

I am using the new Clang Code Model in Qt Creator 4.8 to highlight violations in the editor.

Recently I introduced some experimental C++20 functions in my code. These functions are integrated using a GCC header (`<experimental/source_location>`) that introduces three intrinsics that are unknown to clang:

```
__builtin_FILE()
__builtin_FUNCTION()
__builtin_LINE()
```

As a result, the clang code model run fails (indicated above the editor as a yellow warning sign) due to parsing errors.

Is there a way in Qt Creator to supply dummy replacement macros for those symbols so the clang parser succeeds? Is there some configuration/setting in Qt Creator? Should I patch the code? Should I pass something to clang as command line arguments? How?

I already tried to define the macros using `#ifdef __clang__ / #endif` but it seems `__clang__` is not defined during code model parser run. I also tried to add a `-D` argument to the clang command line in the code model settings but the "sanity checks" of Qt creator do not allow that.